# The Gradle build for Android fails by producing ZIP64 format exception

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-build

The gradle build fails by producing the following error. 
Is this something which says that the amount of the files are to many? If yes, what kind of solution would be to overcome this problem?

```
com.android.builder.dexing.JarClassFileInput$JarClassFileInputsException: Unable to read jar file ***/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/alpha/debug/0.jar
    at com.android.builder.dexing.JarClassFileInput.entries(JarClassFileInput.java:60)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:799)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$8(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:728)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)



Caused by: com.android.apkzlib.zip.compress.Zip64NotSupportedException: Zip64 EOCD locator found but Zip64 format is not supported.
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.readEocd(ZFile.java:802)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.readData(ZFile.java:596)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:510)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:447)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:433)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.JarClassFileInput.entries(JarClassFileInput.java:57)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a while to find out the real problem, which is **proguard**

To fix it just enforce newer version inside your project by
adding the following lines to your root gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3'
            }
        }
    }
}
```